# Is the closure of a geodesically convex set convex?

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis, geodesic

Is the closure of a geodesically convex set convex? If so, is there a simple proof for it? In $ \mathbb{R}^n $ there is a simple proof for it through convergent sequences. How should I apply it on this generalization?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Some questions: what spaces are you considering (e.g. Riemannian manifolds, (complete) length spaces etc.)? What is a geodesic (locally or globally minimizing)? What does geodesically convex mean?

Comment: I am considering metric spaces together with the T2 axiom (so, the geodesics are minimizing distances). A geodesically convex set is the generalization of convex sets in $ R^n $ to more general spaces. I am considering the metric topology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the following example fits you:

Consider $X := [0,1] \times [0,1[ ~\cup ~\{(0,1),(1,1)\} \subset \mathbb R^2$, equipped with the induced metric, and $Y := [0,1] \subset \mathbb R$, again equipped with the induced metric. Now form the topological space $Z = X \cup Y /\sim$ obtained by the disjoint union where the points $(0,1)$ and $0$, respectively $(1,1)$ and $1$, are identified. A metric on $Z$ is determined by

$d(p,q) := \text{ minimal length of a continuous curve in } Z \text{ from } p \text{ to } q,$

where length is defined in the obvious way here. Then the set $[0,1] \times [0,1[$, considered as a subset of $Z$, is geodesicaly convex but its closure (given by $X \subset Z$) is not.

Comment: Oh, I see your nice counterexample. Thank you!
However, I guess that for a Riemannian metric the generalization of the $ R^n $ case with the usual topology is hold.

Comment: For a Riemannian manifold one would first need to define 'geodesically convex' more carefully. Since geodesics between two points points are not unique, and also geodesics are only locally minimizing, there are various natural generalizations of convexity.